Creating two virtual monitors from one physical monitor using xrandr
I want to split my
MEDION® 58,4 cm/23” LED-Backlight Monitor MEDION® AKOYA® X55999 (MD 20444) BTW that is placed right to another Monitor with the same resolution.
It's the HDMI-0 monitor with a resolution of 1920x1080 and a size of probably 510x287mm
Plan/Idea:
I tried the following commands:
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --off
xrandr --setmonitor VIRTUAL1 960x1080+0+0 HDMI-0
xrandr --setmonitor VIRTUAL2 960x1080+960+0 HDMI-0

then log out and log in again.
but its 90degrees placed (high is 1920 and width is 1080)
So I have also tried these commands with alternative syntax:
I tried also:
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --off
xrandr --setmonitor VIRTUAL1 1080x960+0+0 HDMI-0
xrandr --setmonitor VIRTUAL2 1080x960+0+960 HDMI-0

I always got the following errors:
xrandr: failed to parse '.....' as monitor geometry

Additional Information:
Kubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
Graphics Platform: X11
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

xrandr program version       1.5.2
Server reports RandR version 1.6

have read:
I have read:
Splitting monitor using xrandr
and I have read:
xrandr --help
